# Install virtual package of specified version

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies

There is a VCS repo that has 2 branches - `master` and `release`. There are also 2 Debian packages that are built from these branches - let's say `foo` for the `release` branch and `foo-master` for the `master` branch. In the `Provides` section they both have just `foo`

Package `foo` is of version `1.5`, the other one is of version `1.6`.
There is also another package, let's say `bar`, that depends on the package `foo`.

The problem is how to install the package `bar` with the latest version of the package `foo`. When I specify `foo (<< 1.7)` as a dependency of `bar`, it still installs `foo` of version `1.5`. But if I rewrite it as `foo (>= 1.6)` it installs the latest version of `foo`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you running `apt-get install -t [reponame] foo=foo-1.6` to install `foo`?

Comment: @kemotep I'm trying to install this package indirectly, as a dependency of the package `bar`

Comment: @HenryBarker did rebuilding the package help solve your issue? This is very vague, using `foo` and `bar`, you may get better answers if you specify the exact packages and repository you are having issues with.